# How to disable a QPushButton when deselect a QCheckBox

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qcheckbox

I'm working in a Qt project where the user can enable or disable a QPushButton by selecting or deselecting a QCheckBox.
I have already developed a function where the mouse event enable the QPushButton, but the problem is that when i deselect the QCheckBox the QPushButton remain enabled.
Is there a Qt function to disable a button when QCheckBox are unchecked?

This is the code i wrote:

```
//Class.h
//Function to enable the button
private slots:
   void on_QCheckBox_clicked();
//Class.cpp
void class::on_QCheckBox_clicked() {
  ui->QPushButton->setEnabled(true);
  //Here i enabled the button with setEnabled function
}
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code, so we can check that.

Comment: This is the relevant part of the code...other isn't about this problem.

Comment: There is a signal named QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state), you should use it. Also you should provide the code that connects the signals together

Comment: Qt5: `QObject::connect(pQTglBtnEn, &QCheckBox::toggled, pQBtn, &PushButton::setEnabled);` with `QCheckBox *pQTglBtn;` and `QPushButton *pQBtn;`

Comment: Qt4: `QObject::connect(pQTglBtnEn, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), pQBtn, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));` with `QCheckBox *pQTglBtn;` and `QPushButton *pQBtn;`

Comment: Thanks @Scheff!
Yours solution works!

Comment: Yes, I know. ;-) You find a similar sample in my answer for [SO: QPushButton doesn't update when setDown is called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45267593/7478597). While toying around in my local code I added exactly the feature you asked  for (and tested it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Scheff!

I solved by using [`QObject::connect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-2) to connect my QCheckBox and my QPushButton together

Here is an example:

```
class::class() {
  QObject::connect(ui->QCheckBox, &QCheckBox::toggled, ui->QPushButton, &QPushButton::setEnabled);
  //Where ui->QCheckBox is the checkbox and ui->QPushButton is your button
}
```

Comment: Have you really named your objects `QCheckBox` and `QPushButton`? That's really confusing.

Comment: Oh god no, It's just for this site ;-)

Comment: @CMz So you name them horribly just to confuse everyone here? Please change that. It's really really bad and throws anyone reading this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the state using [`QCheckBox::checkState()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcheckbox.html#checkState) as follows:

```
if (QCheckBox->checkState() == Qt::Unchecked)
{
    ui->QPushButton->setEnabled(false);
}
```